# REST API for Docker Hub Registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry

The REST API for registry.hub.docker.com does not seem to match the documented API.

For example, `curl -k https://registry.hub.docker.com/v1/repositories/busybox/tags` returns:

> [{"layer": "4986bf8c", "name": "latest"}, {"layer": "2aed48a4", "name": "buildroot-2013.08.1"}, ... ]

But https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/registry_api/#tags says it should return a map of tag -> id.  That's what I see when I make a similar request to a registry I'm running locally.

Is the REST API for the Docker Hub Registry supposed to be different for some reason?
Is this a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like instead of returning

`[_tag_ : _id_]`

it returns

`[{"layer: _id_, "name": _tag_}]`

But you've got the same information at the end of the day.

Check out this [docs](https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/hub_registry_spec/#get-all-tags), because registry api seems to behave slightly differently than the hub.

Comment: Thanks.  It is strange that the registry API and docker hub API are very similar, but not identical.